# how do i get form to act based on selected dropdown using php

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, laravel

I have created one input type for uploading and deleting a file and a dropdown which consists of 2 options. On selecting dropdown of upload file it shall upload the file and selecting the dropdown of delete file it shall delete the file. After clicking on the submit button the selected option shall be performed. I am facing an error of undefined array.

Front end:

```html
<?php
  include "dbconfig.php"; // includes database connection details 
?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>file upload operations</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-size: border-box; // 
    }

    form {
      display: block; //  specifies if/how an element is displayed.
      text-align: center; // align the elements in center 
      margin-top: 30px; // 
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #CCCCFF;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100vh;
      text-color: white;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
      background-color: #FF6600; // consist of submit button background
      color: white; //  button text color white 
      padding: 12px 20px; // 
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049; // on hovering submit button it will change to this color
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="loadPage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="theForm" id="theForm"> // it will load loadpage.php which contains switch loop for performing action on selected dropdown Select a file to perform a specific operations
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br><br><br><br> // input type for uploading and deleting the file
      <select form="theForm" name="selectedPage">// selects the page
        <option value="page_1">upload file </option> // dropdown option for uploading the file
        <option value="page_2">delete file </option> // dropdown option for deleting the file
      </select><br><br><br><br><br><br> // for next line space after dropdown
      <input type="submit" value="Load page" /> this button will load the page based on selected dropdown
      <input type="submit" value="Cancel"> // cancel button
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for the loading page on basis of selected dropdown:

```
<?php
  $requested_page = $_POST['selectedPage']; // selects the requested page 

  switch($requested_page) {  // switch case for selecting requested page
    case "page_1":
      header("Location: upload.php");// on selecting upload file upload action will be performed
      break;
    case "page_2":
      header("Location: delete.php");// on selecting upload file upload action will be performed
      break;
    default :
      echo "No page was selected";
      break;
  }
?>
```

deletepage.php

```
<?php
  $target_dir = "uploads/"; // directory where files are uploaded 
  $fileName = basename($_FILES["fileToDelete"]["name"]);
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToDelete"]["name"]); // location of target file

  if(isset($_POST["Delete"])) //action on clicking deleted button 
  {
    if (!unlink($target_file)) // unlinks the targeted file
    {
      echo ("$target_file cannot be deleted due to an error"); // error message after file was not deleted due to an error
    }
    else 
    {
      echo ("$target_file has been deleted"); // error message after deleting selected target file
    }
  }
?>
```

I am getting this error after running my code

> Warning: Undefined array key "fileToDelete" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fileuploadoperations\delete.php on line 5

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fileuploadoperations\delete.php on line 5

> Warning: Undefined array key "fileToDelete" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fileuploadoperations\delete.php on line 6

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fileuploadoperations\delete.php on line 6

Comment: You access superglobals ($_POST, $_FILES, ...) without checking if the desired key exists. If no POST was made, then there is simply no information in $_POST or $_FILES.

Comment: @HonkderHase WHAT changes shall i make in loadpage.php file because  this code is working if am taking separate inputs for file upload and delete with different form actions  and buttons for each input type and there i am directly giving form actions

Comment: You must add checks for the existence of POST/FILES entries...

Comment: so i need to add if(isset($post) inside loadpage.php right ?

Comment: @HonkderHase so i need to add if(isset($post) inside loadpage.php right ?

Comment: Yes... or said the other way around: do not access an array-offset without making sure, that it existst (well, also make sure it *is* actually an array, but in case of superglobals that is for sure)

Comment: @HonkderHase can you please help me by modifying my code  still i am not getting this

Comment: @HonkderHase i have tried all methods still no success

Comment: @CBroe can you please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access $_FILES without checking if it exist
you should wrap it in `isset` function something like this

```
if(isset( $_FILES["fileToDelete"] ) && !empty( $_FILES["fileToDelete"]["name"] )){
// code here
}
```

this will do the job